# U-boot embedded devices

Tags: u-boot

I'm working on an IP camera of mine and trying to get into single user mode. I have tried `init=bin/bash`, `init=bin/sh`, `single 1`, etc. When I change the bootargs and go to boot, it just boots up like normal, not even recognizing the commands.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a printout of my original printenv:

```
bootcmd=sf probe 0;sf read 84000000 770000 10000;logoload 84000000;decjpg;sf  read 82000000 30000 400000;squashfsload 82000000;bootm 0x82000000
bootdelay=1
baudrate=115200
bootfile="uImage"
restore=1


bootargs=mem=96M console=ttyAMA0,115200 root=1f01 rootfstype=squashfs mtdparts=hi_sfc:192K(boot),1984K(romfs),3776K(usr),1664K(custom),64K(logo),512K(mtd)
```

Comment: CFG_BOOT_ADDR:0x0
0ff:0x84000000
### /UbootLogo UbootLogoload complete: 19650 bytes loaded to 0x8e800000
jpeg decoding ...
<<addr=0x8e800000, size=0xb85f9, vobuf=0x8e800000>>
<<imgwidth=800, imgheight=600, linebytes=1600>>
decode success!!!!
decode jpeg success. 
decode jpeg!

Comment: srcAddr 0x82000000, dstAddr 0x82000000
find_squashfs_file: name bin, start_block 0, offset 1284, type 1
find_squashfs_file: name boot, start_block 0, offset 1376, type 1
read inode: name boot, sb 0, of 1376, type 1
find_squashfs_file: name zImage.img, start_block 0, offset 1316, type 2
read inode: name zImage.img, sb 0, of 1316, type 2
### FS load complete: 1613452 bytes loaded to 0x82000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 82000000 ...
   Image Name:   linux
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image 
   Data Size:    1613388 Bytes = 1.5 MiB
   Load Address: 80008000

Comment: Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33972521/edit) to add more info on your question instead of putting it in the comments.